# Azure Log Analytics - Cannot add data source

Tags: azure-log-analytics

I have setup a Log Analytics Workspace, install MMA on a few computers with correct workspace id and workspace key (heartbeats are logged). The location of the workspace is set to North Europe.

I cannot add data sources, as shown here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/data-sources-windows-events

I have this view in "Advanced settings" for the workspace:[advanced settings in azure portal for workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kj7r1.png)

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you have required access as [per this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/manage-access#manage-access-using-azure-permissions), I believe it (Advanced settings tile) opens up as expected after waiting for little longer i.e., say ~10 seconds or so!

Comment: Thank you for the link, the workspace has "Use resource or workspace permissions" so this is not the reason for me not being able to change the advanced settings.

I tried to change permissions, to see if it had any effect. -not the result was the same..

Comment: Ah! If that's the case, can you double check if you have any non-english characters in resource group and/or Log Analytics workspace resource ID. If Yes, may be that's the cause of the issue because as per [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/resource-name-rules#microsoftoperationalinsights) doc; only alphanumerics and hyphens are valid characters. Why I brought this up is because recently I have observed same issue for another customer who has used japanese characters in resource ID and removing those resolved the issue. Hope this input helps!

Comment: No special chars, only A-z letters and hyphens. It is really strange. The same counts for the ressource group.